# How to ignore Unexpected element situation in JAXB?

Tags: xml, jaxb

How can one ignore Unexpected element situation in JAXB ans still get all other kind of javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException?

```
obj = unmler.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml))
```

Notice i still want to get the obj result of the xml parsing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The solution.

In JAXB implementing ValidationEventHandler like so:

```
class CustomValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler{

    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Event Info: "+evt);
        if(evt.getMessage().contains("Unexpected element"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then

```
Unmarshaller u = ...;

u.setEventHandler(new CustomValidationEventHandler());

u.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
```

Comment: In my case "if(evt.getMessage().contains("Unexpected element")) " should be "if(evt.getMessage().toLowerCase().contains("unexpected element"))". I don't know why but the event's message sometimes gets in lower case.

Comment: Watch out - the error message is localizable (depends on `Locale.getDefaultLocale()`)!! For example with `Locale.GERMAN` it's "unerwartetes Element".

Answer (score 4):

Also, JAXB 2.0 automatically ignores unrecognized elements and continues the unmarshalling process.  See https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/jaxb20-fcs/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html and jump to "Validation and Well-Formedness".

Answer (score 0):

Use `JAXB.unmarshal()` which ignores unexpected elements by default. Be careful, since it will also skip schema validation.

JavaDoc:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXB.html