# Any workaround for ignoring unexpected elements in Apache Axis 1.4?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis

The problem was asked before ["Apache AXIS Ignore/Skip additional element while parsing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597558/apache-axis-ignore-skip-additional-element-while-parsing) in 2012 for Apache Axis 2. Is there no workaround yet for Axis 1.4?

**Problem Definition**

For instance;

**1-** We have a soap response definition('ResponseGetCustomerInfo') in our wsdl while development[with *Axis 1.4*]:

```
...
  <xs:element name="ResponseGetCustomerInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:CustomerID"/>
        <xs:element ref="ns1:CustomerUsername"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="CustomerID" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="CustomerUsername" type="xs:string"/>
...
```

**2-** Is good to see that response is parsable when we get like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ResponseGetCustomerInfo xmlns="http://tempUri.org/">
            <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerUsername>raki</CustomerUsername>
        </ResponseGetCustomerInfo>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**3-** After some time, our service provider changed the service response and adds new output fields to response and **we don't know when or why**;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ResponseGetCustomerInfo xmlns="http://tempUri.org/">
            <CustomerID>1</CustomerID>
            <CustomerUsername>raki</CustomerUsername>
            <CustomerName>Raki</CustomerName>
            <CustomerSurname>Bandao</CustomerSurname>
        </ResponseGetCustomerInfo>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

**4-** New response *theoretically compatible with older version because of no field neither deleted nor changed*. But Axis can not parse the response:

```
"SAXException: Invalid Element ... "
```

***I don't want to update wsdl and regenerate web service client again***. So, Is there any way to skip "Unexpected[newly added] elements" in the response? or any workaround?

I am trying many ways, but could not find any solution yet.

Comment: There is an unresolved issue  [AXIS-2758](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2758). I thinks it is similar. Is your service encoding RPC/Encoded? If not, you may want to prefer JAX-WS client which handles changes better.

Comment: @bhdrkn, actually i looking for a "generic" solution. By the way, "JAX-WS" does not support all the service types or WSDL definitions including RPC/Encoding. I know that this is an unresolved problem defined at [AXIS-2758](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2758), if there is any workaround [ like JAXB's [ValidationEventHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/362533/1888799) or any way to exract unexpected elements in the response etc] for the problem, i will be happy :) This problem make me angry too much :\ Every day, every moment...

Answer (score 6):

We always go through this hell due to bad vendors writing these services.

So, unfortunately, there's no way out using parameters for **WSDL2JAVA**, BUT there is a workaround, you'll to re-generate stubs at least once:

1. Replace `xs:sequence` with `xs:all`. This allows elements to be returned in any order, and helps fix a lot of cases, as well as generated stub code which makes it easier for step
2. Sorry, but you for each response bean, you go into its class from the generated code (such as ResponseGetCustomerInfo.java), and instead of this:

```java
while(!reader.isStartElement() && !reader.isEndElement())
   reader.next();

if(reader.isStartElement())
// A start element we are not expecting indicates a trailing invalid
// property
throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("Unexpected subelement " + reader.getLocalName());
```

Have this:

```java
while(!reader.isStartElement() && !reader.isEndElement())
   reader.next();

// if(reader.isStartElement())
// A start element we are not expecting indicates a trailing invalid
// property

// The below is commented, to prevent unexpected result parameters from causing an exception
// (As well as the condition above is removed)
//  throw new org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException("Unexpected subelement " + reader.getLocalName());
```

It's tested and works at least better than no solution.

Comment: thank you for your response. It's a solution, but a bit messy :) Developer may forget this changes after updating web service client, there must be a solution which is not require to change 'auto generated' code :|, however i looking a solution[or workaround] for Axis 1.4 :) Not for CXF or any other tool.

Comment: There's no solution, at least not for Axis2 1.5.4.
Trust me, I've been working with Axis2 services for 4 years almost now.
Plz upvote my answer, i need points desperately lol

Comment: after two bounties, there is no answer for Axis 1.4, i wish to some answers will be shared in the future, but doesn't seem nowadays :\ so i give you the bounty for helping about points...

Comment: Thanks! Further looking into it, the generation parameter for ignoring unexpected parameters is not even in any stable version: it's in 1.7, stil unstable.

Answer (score 1):

Not having used Axis 1.4, but after a quick glance at the docs.

You can add a Handler to your code. You should be able even do this without having to recompile it, it that's an issue. A Handler wraps the underlying web service, it's called before the service is invoked, and after it returns. It's sorta like a Servlet Filter, but for Web Services.

The Handler has full access to the SOAP body before it gets sent forward for processing. So you can use this as an opportunity to remove elements that you don't like.

Dig a bit and you'll find you eventually get a DOM element that represents your SOAP body, so you can play primitive DOM games to add/delete nodes, etc. and set that back all within the Handler.

Your service will never see the new nodes in the edit SOAP body.

All that said, you may well be able to even do this using a Servlet Filter as well.

Comment: i already use `Handler`s for saving request/response XML's, but you know if i want to extract elements as a `generic way`, i have to parse WSDL definition seperately. This is not good for performance :( I think Axis already know WSDL definition, but i can not say to ignore elements that you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Metro library instead of Axis, it worked for me in October 2014. Please, ignore this suggestion if you must use Axis library.

Using Axis 2 library to create a Java client that calls .NET WCF service (communicating over the Internet securely), we got errors generating Java client class from WSDL. As a workaround, we switched to a different library, Metro 2.3, and we were able to generate Java client that runs without any problems.

One of the important steps to getting a successful secure web service call from Java was configuring client and server certificates.

Comment: please make sure that you unserstand the general concept of stackoverflow  before posting.

Comment: @whaefelinger: I have edited my answer to state more clearly that our solution was to switch from Axis library to Metro. If you have specific suggestions for improving this answer, let us know please.

Comment: well, better than before. However, the original poster got *runtime*exceptions based on unexpected elements (i.e. the server runs an updated WSDL) while you were dealing with compile time problems. How does Metro handle unexpected or missing elements?