# How to Ignore unavailable fields from a SOAP Response

Tags: java, soap

I have a web service developed in SOAP, for which a client is generated already. Now I am adding a new field in response of web service. Now when I am invoking the client it gives error as the updated field is not available in Data Class available at client side.Is there any way to Ignore those property which are not available in data class while unmarshaling. the same works fine in REST. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in `REST` because with `HTTP` only you don't have such a strict protocol of communication as it is with `SOAP` over `HTTP`. In `SOAP` a more restrictive and detailed technical contract is in place by default and both sides must comply with it. If you want the same behavior of `REST` you'd have to implement validation and rules yourself since it is a bit *open* and that is part a of the idea.

To solve your issue, you'll probably need to regenerate your client proxy/stub class, using the new `WSDL` file in order to make the client aware that a new field have been added and could be expected in the response of the server. You can also add this field manually to the response in your current stub class and mark it as optional, without using any of the auto-generating tools.

If you want to avoid breaking clients altogether (and regenerating/modifying classes) when you introduce changes in the future, you may try:

1. Creating new service version for new consumers, maintaining both - old and new version, making the new available only to new consumers;
2. Creating a new service operation for new consumers in the same service, maintaining both - old and new operation, making the new available only to new consumers;
3. Mark fields as optional - attribute `minOccurs=0` in the `WSDL` (only possible when this is allowed by your use case). See [XML Schema Indicators](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_indicators.asp). In short in your WSDL, your element must look something like this: 
   `<xs:element name="el_name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>`. Try this way, without updating the contract at client side. Again, it depends on how strict the client is about following the contract.
4. Try and see if there are any specific options in Java to make the client more tolerant to optional values - for example - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27102778/510615))*

These approaches are useful if you have many clients you cannot modify and you do not want to break communication contract with them. Be aware that all the above options come at a cost - you'll trade more maintenance and governance on your side for increased compatibility with clients. So choose wisely.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Plamen , currently we are using approach 1 and 2, I am interested in approach 3. we are exposing soap using Jboss and wsdl is auto generated. so can you help with the annotation to mark field as optional.

Comment: I already hae minOccurs =0 for all fields and it doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you update the proxy stub in the client? Or you want to do this while avoiding update of the stub?

Comment: I want to add some more fields in response, and keep it running from old client using same stub

Comment: I guess then, you're stuck with options 1 and 2. However, there is a Java workaround described here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/27102778/510615), but still, it needs one regeneration of the stub initially. I don't know if it fits your case.

Comment: This is first done in the server, then a new wsdl is gnerated, that is much more "liberal". Then you regenerate your client according to this wsdl once, and from then on, any added fields shouldn't break the client.

Comment: Code is for Axis and I dont have Axis. I am generating client code using Eclipse

Comment: Replacing xs:sequence with xs:all is not at all about Axis. This is a general contract design approach that makes the contract a bit more extensible/flexible, while sacrificing some of the concreteness. This solves your problem.